# How to improve the performance of a LINQ query that compares two lists?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

The query below does what I want, but it is very slow when the two lists have many items (> 300 thousand).

Basically, it returns all people on list 2 who do not have documents in list 1.

```
        personList1.Add(person1);
        personList1.Add(person2);

        personList2.Add(person2);
        personList2.Add(person3);

        var result = personList2
                    .Where(p2 => p2.documents
                        .Exists(d2 => !personList1
                            .Exists(p1 => p1.documents
                                .Contains(d2)
                            )
                        )
                    ).ToList();

        result.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.name));
        //Should return person3 name
```

Classes

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<IdentificationDocument> documents { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        documents = new List<IdentificationDocument>();
    }
}

public class IdentificationDocument
{
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

Full code

https://dotnetfiddle.net/gS57gV

Anyone know how to improve query performance? Thank you!

Comment: And why `John`?

Comment: if you can change the `Person` class, try to change `List<IdentificationDocument>` to `HashSet<IdentificationDocument>`. You might want to override `GetHashCode`  as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all relevant data in a structure made for lookup first:

```
var lookup = new HashSet<string>(personList1.SelectMany(p => p.documents).Select(d => d.number));

var result = personList1.Where(p => !p.documents.Select(d => d.number).Any(lookup.Contains));
```